# Sharepoint API CORS access using Angular

Tags: angular, sharepoint, cors, angular-http, sharepoint-api

I would get data from SharePoint API.

When I attack the API I get CORS access error.

Here's my service.

```
  public getResults() {
    let url;
    let mockUrl;
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    });

    url ="https://my.sharepoint.api";
    return this.httpClient
    .get(url, headers)      
 }
```

The team working on this project told me that they are working with other angular applications and they don't need to change their server configuration ( to allow localhost calls)

Here's what I get as a response:

> GET https://my.api.sharepoint 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> Failed to load https://my.api.sharepoint: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

How can I solve that ?

Comment: Maybe the other angular team are going through a proxy for their requests? Btw, specifying `"Access-Control-Allow-...` headers angular side is useless; these headers should be set server side on the API

Answer (score 0):

You need enable cross domain call for SharePoint 2013(this not work for SharePoint 2016).

And add http://localhost:31699 to trust site so the request will use current user credential for authentication.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0

$localFarm = Get-SPFarm

$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sp:12001"

# Remove old web.config modifications of MyAuthenticationProvider
$oldMods = @();
$webapp.WebConfigModifications | ? { $_.Owner -eq "CrossSiteScripting" } | % { 
    $oldMods = $oldMods + $_
}

$oldMods | % { 
    $webapp.WebConfigModifications.Remove($_) 
}

# update the Web Application and apply all existing web.config modifications - this executes the "remove" actions from above
$webapp.Update()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep 1
}

# New web.config modifications for MyAuthenticationProvider
$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin'][@value='http://localhost:31699']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
#0 = for the enum value "SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin' value='http://localhost:31699' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Method'][@value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Method' value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Headers'][@value='Content-Type,Authorization']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Headers' value='Content-Type,Authorization' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'][@value='true']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' value='true' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$webapp.Update()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I solved on the client by installing the plugin that you can find in the link (if you have chrome).
This is an option that is only good if you are doing some tests.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=it&gl=IT

Comment: it's for production